# Purpose of Document.all.item method's second argument

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I'm converting some VBS to JS and have come across a line I'm unsure about:

```
document.all.item(strCheckboxName,i)
```

As there is no *constructor* taking 2 arguments for `document.getElementById()`, I have no clue of what this instruction was meant to do.

In other words, what is the purpose of the second argument `i` here ?

```
document.all.item(strCheckboxName, i)
```

Comment: In JS, the argument to `.item` *should* be the index you want to look up, and nothing else. `document.all.item(i)` might work - or `document.all[i]`, or, even better, avoid `document.all` altogether

Comment: My question is: what is the purpose of the second parameter with: document.all.item(strCheckboxName,i) ?

Comment: In Javascript, there isn't any - only the first argument matters AFAIK

Comment: Lol.. yes I understand that.. but if I have to convert document.all.item(strCheckboxName,i) then I have to understand what it's doing first.

Comment: There's not enough context to say - there's nothing in the question that explains what your `strCheckboxName` or `i` is, or what exactly you're trying to select. The best solution would be to replace it completely with `querySelector` if possible

Comment: Lol omg.. x = document.all.item(strValue1) will return/set x to the control 'strValue1'.. but what does the second parameter do? Do you know?

Comment: Like I already said, the second parameter doesn't do anything in Javascript, see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item)

Comment: Am I being trolled, lol, what does the second parameter do in VBS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` method (`object.item(name, index)`) takes the following parameters:

**name** [in]

Specifies the object or collection to retrieve. If this parameter is an integer, it is the zero-based index of the object. If this parameter is a string, all objects with matching attribute name or id properties are retrieved, and a collection is returned if more than one match is made.

**index** [in, **optional**]

Specifies the zero-based index of the object to retrieve when a collection is returned.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//hh870051(v=vs.85)

---

What this means to you is that if `strCheckboxName` refers to a control array, you would use the second parameter to specify which object in the array. It's an optional parameter.